# counter taking last incremented value in Java script

Tags: javascript

I am making a counter app for learning, after giving the counter name the counter increments by 1 on an onclick event this is working fine when there is only counter but if I add multiple names it takes the last increment value on the **new counter** , basically increments should be separate for each newly created counter.

```js
let counter = 0

function updateCount() {
  let progressCountUpdate = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-count")
  for (var i = 0; i < progressCountUpdate.length; i++) {
    progressCountUpdate[i].onclick = function () {
      this.childNodes[1].innerText = counter++
    }
  }
}

function createProgress() {
  progressCount = document.createElement("div")
  progressCount.className = "progress-count"
  progressNameNew = document.createElement("span")
  progressNameNew.innerText = progresslabel.value;
  progressNameNew.className = 'progress-name'
  progressCountNumber = document.createElement("span")
  progressCountNumber.innerText = 0
  progressCountNumber.className = "progress-counter"
  progressCount.appendChild(progressNameNew)
  progressCount.appendChild(progressCountNumber)
  progressDisplay.appendChild(progressCount)
  progresslabel.value = ""
  updateCount()
}

addbutton.onclick = function () {
  if (progresslabel.value === "") {
    alert("enter progress name")
  } else {
    checkStartEndTime();
    createProgress();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-display"></div>
```

How do I ensure increments are independent for each counter.

Comment: Please also post the html part.

Comment: @Gh05d html part is just a div, rest of the content is created by events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a closure function in order to add a counter to each individual `onclick` function like so:

```js
function updateCount() {
  let progressCountUpdate = document.getElementsByClassName("progress-count");

  for (let el of progressCountUpdate) {
    if (el.getAttribute('hasOnClick') !== 'true') {
      el.onclick = (function() {
        const childNode = el.childNodes[1];
        let counter = 0;

        el.setAttribute('hasOnClick', 'true'); // set a flag so it won't reset every update

        return function() {
          return childNode.innerText = counter++;
        }
      })();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: even doing so, on adding a new counter name it starts from 0 but if I now try to update old counters it just starts from the last incremented value. e.g. new counter value = 10, old counter = 21, on clicking the old counter again the count starts from 11 and so forth.

Comment: I want is that both counters should have their own individual increments

Comment: ok I edited my answer. I think I understand now what you are trying to do. If I got it wrong please let me know

Comment: thank you for taking time for this I really appreciate it :). What is happening now is, whenever I add a new counter *all previous counters resets to 1 as in the increment start from 1* again this is only happening whenever a new counter is added but otherwise it works as intended.

Comment: I added a flag to the element so it won't reset every time you run the `updateCount` function